# POST request failing when in 3G

Tags: android, http, post, ksoap2, 3g

Here is the deal:
I have a simple app which connects and communicates with a tomcat service.
It works fine on wifi, but fails on 3G.

The stacktrace with HttpTransportSE's debug attribute set to true tells me that it couldn't read the error message, as if it was simply not connected:

```
java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:279)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.readDebug(HttpTransportSE.java:273)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:241)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
```

if I set debug to false, all it gives me is HTTP 400.

Here's the caller:

```
httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(service, PING_TIMEOUT);
httpTransport.debug = true;

SoapSerializationEnvelope pack = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
pack.setOutputSoapObject(ping);
httpTransport.call("", pack);
```

this simple...
Is it a google security measure or something? Should I use SSL? Any ideas?

Comment: The device is a Samsung Galaxy S III mini (GT-I8190L). We reset it to factory and it's now working. 
The answer to this question however should tell us "What could the client do in the device that blocked post requests through 3G?" 
Is there anything such as firewall for android?

Comment: I wonder. How and if you have solved this problem?

Comment: I reset to factory settings
there was something on the phone blocking it

Comment: A friend found this solution. Basically involves disabling usage of proxies when opening URL.openConnection() with Proxy.NONE https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36431#c11

Comment: In our case the problem was/is that the carriers is using some kind of proxy. Probably for monitoring purposes and that software had some kind of strange bug. Switching carriers of course helped also without using Proxy.None.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I needed 3 days to find this little question. Thanks Oto :)